# Solving this Differential Equation by switching variables.

Tags: integration

$ \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{mg-cv^2}{m} $ where m, c and g are constants $>0$

My attempts to solve this have been as follows:

$ \frac{dt}{dv} = \frac{m}{mg-cv^2} $

$ t=\int{ \frac{m}{mg-cv^2}}dv $

I am however now unsure about how to solve this integral. I have tried substituting $u=x^2$ into the expression, but integration by substitution isn't really helping. Thoughts?

Comment: Use partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

As $m,g,c $ are constants and if $c\neq 0$ take out $c $ common from denominator so we have $t=\int \frac {m}{c (\sqrt {\frac {mg}{c}})^2-v^2)}dv$ let $\sqrt {\frac {mg}{c}}=a$ so  we have $t=\int \frac {1}{a^2-v^2}dv $ which can be solved by partial fractions.